# Why I am getting this issue while running thrift server SparkSQL and hive?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect the SparkSQL and Hive so that I can query the hive tables using SparkSQL.  Here is my program:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
    try{
    spark.sql("select * from health").show();}
    catch(Exception AnalysisException){ System.out.println("table not found");}
```

But I encountered an issue while running the program. Here is the issue:

Here are the issue: https://justpaste.it/13n4r

I have checked the same code on my laptop and it was running fine. But when I shift to my Desptop computer I came across this issue while running a maven program using Eclipse Neon.
I am using Apache Spark 2.1.0 and Hive 1.2.0
It is not an issue due to the versions. I am sure about this. But I do not understand what is the problem and what I can do to avoid it. Kindly help me.

Comment: Do you have exact configuration of hive on your Desktop? Recheck your hive-site.xml for authentication/security configurations. Try by restarting services on Desktop.

Comment: @abaghel how I can do that. please let me know. I have the same setting of hive-site.xml on both the systems. I suppose.

Comment: Your log has "java.net.BindException: Address already in use". Can you check if spark is already running on your Desktop. Or check the applications which are using that port. Recheck what services/applications you are running on Desktop and restart them if required.

Comment: @abaghel I have checked it but still my process is getting halted for a long on this step: `INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9083`

Comment: is there any solution?